# Can I keep winning games after the Holiday Gift Pile promotion is over?

Tags: steam, achievements

As part of the Steam Holiday Sale, we've all been earning achievements that grant us coal, coupons, and (rarely) free games.  There's been more than one achievement that I've put off due to its complexity and the amount of free time I have left.

However, today I noticed the following on the Gift Pile achievement list:

> If you unlock an achievement on or after 12/31 your prize will be a free Valve game, a coupon toward a Valve game, or Holiday Coal.

Does this mean that even after the contest ends today, I can still get free coupons or games for getting achievements in these games?  What about achievements that require specific holiday scenarios or unlocks in order to work?  What use is Holiday Coal after the contest ends?  It is only for crafting?

It may be possible to test this in an hour or two (after the contest closes, and assuming that Valve rolls out the end-of-contest update on time) but has there been any modification to the rules or any official word on what these achievements mean after the end of the contest?

Comment: [Something to keep in mind for the Steam giveaway](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2428973) Apparently, they ran out of third party prizes, so they're only giving away Valve-related items. Also, I really hope the syntax for the link worked.

Comment: Isn't this "too localised...to a specific moment in time"? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#close

Comment: @Alex Yes, it is. The question already had several close votes for that very reason when you posted that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the deadline is today, at 10 AM PST (about 45 minutes from now). The notice serves to inform people that as of December 31, all third-party coupons and games are gone, leaving only Valve stuff and coal.

Comment: Oooh, I missed the Valve part.  That would explain my confusion.